# Magento 2 Postcode Field Hidden

Tags: magento2, checkout

I'm working on a Magento 2 site but the postcode field does not show up on checkout.

It must be disabled somewhere in the code, but I just can't see where.
I've changed to blank theme and disabled all external modules, but still no postcode.

I've looked in the config, but can't see anything there either.

Help?

Comment: navigate to your magento directory in terminal and run this command.
grep -irl 'item name="postcode"' ./ --exclude-dir={var,pub,generated}

Check what it returns.

Comment: ./vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/di.xml
./vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml
./vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
./vendor/magento/module-inventory/etc/di.xml

Comment: Now check in each file if any file is having below code under postcode or not.

<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

Comment: No unfortunately not, everything appears to be untouched in the vendor code.